# Is it possible to use dual authentication with symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to use dual authentication with symfony2?

Users should be able to authenticate themselves with facebook and my own system.

I've read the documentation, and I know that there is the FacebookBundle with I can authenticate a user with facebook, but I don't know how to combinate the two.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. "You can configure a firewall to use more than one authentication mechanisms" : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-multiple-user-providers

I didn't try it yet but I think it should be something like:

```
security:
    firewalls:
         public:
             pattern:   ^/.*
             form_login: true
             fos_facebook:
                 login_path: ^/facebook$
                 check_path: ^/facebook-check$
                 default_target_path: /facebook
                 provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
```

You can define multiple providers as well.